# Converting standard numbers to decimal

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

Whenever I insert a value like: 1 into a decimal field it will immediately rejects it. Is there any code in PHP to convert a value of say "1" to "01.00" or "1.00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format). A sample usage in your case:

```
echo number_format(1, 2, '.', '');
```

will echo `1.00`. Now, to use it in query to insert, surround it with quotes and do it like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (Amount)
             VALUES ('" . number_format($your_number), 2, '.', '') . "')";
```

Comment: The return value of `number_format()` is a string, so that would probably not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: This code worked, thanks for the example too ;) I can only click the tick in 7 mins though.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if he prepares his statements correctly, since the SQL is a string itself.

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe, good to know :) You *may* also consider to upvote it, if you like it.

Comment: @Brian H, true, and I have to admit that I have never run into this problem myself...

Answer (score 1):

the right way to format any number to the desired string representation is the sprintf function: https://www.php.net/sprintf

Comment: or at least that would be the most flexible way

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a number to a float like for example:

```
$x = (float) $x;
```

or:

```
$x = floatval($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it reject it?  Are you wrapping it with quotes or something?  Anyway, to convert, use the number_format() function.

Comment: The return value of `number_format()` is a string, so that would probably not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: The database query is a big string anyway, so whether the numeric value is represented in PHP as a string or number shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Pickle That´s true if you use a conventional sql statement, I´m not sure about a prepared statement (PDO / mysqli). Anyway, I´ve never had this problem, nor with conventional sql, nor with PDO so I´m guessing there was a problem with the sql and not so much with the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$num = 1;
print number_format($num , 2);
```